# Lenovo IdeaPad Z580 wireless card driver for Fedora linux

Tags: linux, drivers, network-adapter, lenovo-laptop

I installed Fedora 17 on my Lenovo IdeaPad Z580 laptop, but the wireless card is not showing up when I do `sudo iwconfig`. I am quite sure that it is only a driver issue, because when I boot into Windows 8, the wireless works fine. I have searched the Internet, but I can not a driver that works. I do not even know which wireless card is in it.
If anyone knows what wireless card is in a Z580, or if anyone knows which driver I need, please help.
Thanks in advance.

*****EDIT*****

`lspci -vv` reported the wireless card as an Intel® PRO/Wireless 3945ABG. I loaded `iwl3945`, thinking that would resolve the problem. But it still didn't show up when I ran `sudo ifconfig` or `sudo iwconfig`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is what I did:
* brought back the laptop
* ordered a used laptop online

I have been reading around, and I think that iwl3945 is the correct driver, so not quite sure why it didn't work, I guess I'll never know.